# перегрузка метода, что будет выполняться

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста почему выполняется второй метод (хотя он стринговый), и при компиляции ругается на преобразование:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Код:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        Gen gen = new Gen();
        gen.m(integerList);
    }

    static class Gen<T> {
        <T> void m(Collection<T> collection) {
            for (T s : collection) {
                System.out.println(s + " Дженерик");
            }
        }
        <T> void m(List<String> list) {
            for (String s : list) {
                System.out.println(s+ " String");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я добавил ошибку, а вы сами в следующий раз сделайте это :)

Comment: Кст, если `Gen` явно тип дженерика указать, то правильный метод будет выбран: `Gen<Integer> gen = new Gen<>()`